# Templating Datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate

I'm creating a ListBox with templated items (DataTemplate). Inside this template I want to have the possibility of changing the way a part of the template is presented depending of the data bounded to it. Here's what I wrote:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Indices}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- ****this does not work ;(**** -->
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                        <tmpl:BoolBasedSelector
                            Value="{Binding IsEditable, ElementName=MainCtrl}"
                            TrueTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxEditableLabel}"
                            FalseTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxNonEditableLabel}" />
                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                </ContentPresenter>

                <!-- other stuff, not important right now -->
                <Button Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**MainCtrl** is the name of the main control within which the grid containing this list is placed.
How do I write ListBox's DataTamplate with exchangeable grid's element? Thanks for you advices.

EDIT:
**tmpl:BoolBasedSelector** is really simple:

```
class BoolBasedSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TrueTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FalseTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container) {
        return Value ? TrueTemplate : FalseTemplate;
    }
}
```

The referenced resources are like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxEditableLable">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Label}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxNonEditableLable">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Indices property of the DataContext to which ListBox binds:

```
interface IIndex {
    string Label { get; set; }
    IIndexValueProvider ValueProvider { get; set; }
    IIndexValidator Validator { get; set; }
    bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    bool IsGrouped { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template uses the static resource names "listBoxEditableLable" and "listBoxNonEditableLabel", but your data template keys are "listBoxEditableLable" and "listBoxNonEditableLable".

Note the different spellings of label. "Label" vs "Lable"